# Show that all irreducible representations of a finite group are finite dimensional.

Tags: representation-theory

Show that all irreducible representations of a finite group are finite dimensional.
We know for any representation $V$ of a finite group $G$, there is a decomposition $V=V_1 \oplus V_2 \oplus.....\oplus V_n$ where $V_i$ s are all irreducibles. Now if we make $V$ irreducibles then just one $V=V_1$(say) will be there. But how can we show $V$ is finite dimensional?

Any help will be apreciated..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pick $v\in V$ nonzero and consider $\Bbb C[G]v$, the $\Bbb C$-span of $v$'s orbit under $G$.

Comment: Ok then what I shall do??

Comment: @user152715 You should be done then.

Comment: Ohh okay. This $\Bbb C Gv$ is a submodule of $V$ and it has only one. So it must be whole of $V$. Sorry...

Comment: But where finiteness of $G$ is used here?

Comment: @user152715: it means that $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: Yeah but we have to show $dim(V)$ is finite. So why are we bothered about $dim (\Bbb C G)$? Am I right or I am making mistakes?

Comment: @user152715: whacka's argument, although very terse, shows you that an irreducible representation $V$ is necessarily a quotient of $\mathbb{C}[G]$; in particular, its dimension is at most the dimension of $\mathbb{C}[G]$. (I don't know why you accepted this answer if you didn't understand it.)

Comment: @user152715 The orbit $Gv=\{gv:g\in G\}$ must be finite because $G$ is finite. And $\Bbb C[G]v$ is the span of this orbit. So $\Bbb C[G]v$ is finite-dimensional. Since $\Bbb C[G]v$ is a nontrivial subrepresentation of $V$, it must be all of $V$. Or as Qiaochu put it, consider the map $\Bbb C[G]\to \Bbb C[G]v$. This means $V$ is a quotient of $\Bbb C[G]$.

Comment: Okay thanks you all are saying that $ℂ[G]$ is a vector space over $\Bbb C$ of dimension $|G|$ I was confused with $\{v\}$. Sorry

Comment: @anon What do you mean by "is a quotient"? Is isomorphic to the quotient space? Is it fair to say that the argument is simply that $\Bbb C[G]v$ is $G$-invariant (one has to show this still, but should be clear) and finite-dimensional (as you mention), and this contradicts the irreducibility of $V$ definitionally?